# What happens when we convert string literal to integer in C?

Tags: c, string, literals, string-literals

Consider a C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int x = 'a';
  printf("%d", x);
}
```

Here the output is `97` as per the ASCII value table.

But in the example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int x ='aa';
  printf("%d", x);
}
```

The output is `24929`.

Can anyone please explain how the literal has been converted to this integer value?

Comment: Your second example do not compile correctly: c is not defined, the x initialization is not correct. I think you've got an undefined behaviour.

Comment: There are no string literals in your code, just character literals.

Comment: Note: The value of multicharacter literals is implementation defined.

Comment: And next time onwards, please post compilable code. I've edited it for you this time.

Comment: @purplepsycho the second example is *implementation-defined* and it should compile correctly

Comment: Those are **not** string literals http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal but rather character literals http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant

Comment: Relace `printf("%d", x);` by `printf("%x", x);` and it will be clearer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: not really – a better test would be with two *different* characters.

Answer (score 3):

> int x ='aa';

This is valid but value of `x` is implementation defined. And btw, this is not a string literal. String literal would be this "aa".

Comment: What do we call it then, actually I could'nt find the name so I wrote string literal.

Comment: @smartnerd Probably multicharacter constant

Answer (score 0):

You assigned a value to the int using octets : `'a'` is `0x61`.

So writing `int x = 'aa'` is like writing `int x = 0x6161`.

Edit: but do not write that. Just write `int x = 0x6161` or `int x = 24929`.